# Why is my nodejs express server connecting to the MongoDB on my local machine and the AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, localhost

I have a MongoDB running on my local machine and another MongoDB running on the AWS EC2 instance where my express server and my angularjs web app is installed. That is:

On my local machine (Windows environment), running:

- MongoDB
- Nodejs Express server

On AWS EC2 instance (ubuntu), running:

- MongoDB
- Nodejs Express server
- AngularJS web app

When I browse my web side running on AWS EC2 instance (using `https://ec2_public_ip:3443/home/app/index.html`), it retrieves data from the MongoDB running on my local machine. If I shut down the MongoDB and Express server on my local machine, I get Failed to connect to resource error. Why is my express server not connecting to the MongoDB running on AWS?

This is my connection string in the app.js file:

```
'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myMongodatabase',
```

I also tried

```
'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/myMongodatabase',
```

Both did not work on my AWS instance.

I'm learning to use MongoDB, AWS, Express and now I am confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that... shouldn't be possible. Possibly mis-interpreted results? localhost on node.js code running on a remote server isn't going to point to your local computer.

Comment: I suspect your Angular webapp is pointing to `http://localhost/api` for its data, which is in turn hitting `mongodb://localhost`.